# CSS code for solid nav menu background on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, elementor

I have a test page i am currently working on - https://www.monofireandsecurity.co.uk/test-page

I want the background of the navigation menu to be transparent on desktop but solid on tablet and mobile. i am using Elementors nav builder but i can only have one set background colour for all three devices

Code i have tried is:

.header.mobile {background-color: #000000;}

but nothing happens

Any help appreciated 
Marc

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [css media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) for this. Media queries can override styles on certain viewport dimensions.

```css
/** 'global' style **/
.elementor-menu .menu-item {
  background-color: #000;
}

/** desktop style **/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .elementor-menu .menu-item { background-color: transparent; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however all this code seems to do is add a 1px red border around my header container apologies if my question wasn't clear enough

Comment: I just put the red border there for illustrations. Remove the  `border` property from my css.

Comment: I also added an `!important` flag after the transparent style.

Comment: apologies once again. it is the drop down menu on mobile and tablet that i require to have a solid background

Comment: Then you could do the same, but replace the `.header` class in your css with the class of the drop down menu container. Likely `.sub-menu`.

Comment: I checked your site. The class should be `.elementor-menu`. I updated my snippet

Comment: the !important tag shouldn't be needed. If you can achieve the same result without using it you should. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css/3706876#3706876

Comment: @Moose i put it in just to be sure there is nothing overriding it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, im 80% of the way there now. Just having an issue with the black background not filling the whole of the navigation drop down menu. the black only covers half of the menu

Comment: @Marcburke you can also style the individual menu items. Replace `.elementor-menu` with `.elementor-menu .menu-item`. That way they will be all black. UPDATED MY SNIPPET

Comment: @Marc Burke: remove height: 110px; from .elementor-nav-menu when the nav turns a dropdown.

Comment: @jrswgtr you are a life saver. thank you so much for your assistance. have a great day

Comment: My pleasure. Can you please mark my answer as correct?